# Throwing error from cfc - cflocation doesn't work from inside onerror()

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, onerror

Edit: an important piece might be that I'm calling a cfc method via ajax...

I'm calling a cfc method via ajax, which returns data for use in a jqgrid table. Inside the cfc's method, I'm trying to set up error handling, so that instead of just failing and giving the user no indication of any problems, I send users to an error page, which is defined as error.cfm in the root directory, and which right now just includes some boilerplate html.
Inside Application.cfc, I've defined my onError() method like so:

```
<cffunction name="onError" returnType="void" output="false"  >
    <cfargument name="exception" required="true"  >
    <cfargument name="eventname" type="string" required="true"  >
    
    <cfmail to="#application.REGISTRATION_NOTIFICATION#" from="outgoing address" subject="Error">
    
    </cfmail>

    <cflocation url="../index.cfm?file=error.cfm" addToken="false"  />
```

When I throw an error from the cfc's method, whether inside a cfcatch or not, Chrome reports that I have indeed been sent to index.cfm with a STATUS=200, and the response shows, correctly, the html that is inside the error.cfm template. However, the browser does not actually go to the page.

The thing is, if I change the location to

```
<cflocation url="index.cfm?file=error.cfm" addToken="false"  />
```

and throw an error from the page which was calling the cfc, instead of from the cfc, cflocation does work as expected. Also, if I use cfinvoke to call the cfc from the original page, instead of using the ajax call, cflocation works. So this must have something to do with the fact that I'm making the call to the cfc through ajax, instead of invoking it from within CF. So what am I missing here?

p.s. this happens in Chrome, IE, and FF. I'm using CF 9.0.1 with hotfixes, no frameworks. Here's a subset of the output from Chrome's Network pane, in Headers, for the referring page:

> Request URL:http://localhost/sitename/cfc/method.cfc
>
> Request Method:GET
>
> Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
>
> Request Headers view source
>
> Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>
> Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
>
> Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
>
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Cookie:CFID=11801; CFTOKEN=90037336; LASTVISIT=1327852981759
>
> Host:localhost
>
> Referer:http://localhost/sitename/index.cfm?file=referringfile.cfm
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7
>
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
>
> Query String Parameters view URL encoded
>
> method:getPartNumbers
>
> filter:{"page":1,"sessionSQL":"1327834969791","filterRows":[{"FIELD_NAME":"PART_NUMBER","OPERAND":"EQUALS","FIELD_VALUE":"11
> 06 01"}]}
>
> _search:false
>
> nd:1327835014639
>
> rows:100
>
> page:1
>
> sidx:PART_NUMBER
>
> sord:desc
>
> Response Headers view source
>
> Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Date:Sun, 29 Jan 2012 11:03:34 GMT
>
> Location:../index.cfm?file=error.cfm
>
> Persistent-Auth:true
>
> Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>
> Set-Cookie:LASTVISIT=1327853014657;expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2012 11:03:34
> GMT;path=/
>
> Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>
> X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

And for the error.cfm page:

> Request URL:http://localhost/sitename/index.cfm?file=error.cfm
>
> Request Method:GET
>
> Status Code:200 OK
>
> Request Headers view source
>
> Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>
> Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
>
> Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
>
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> Authorization:Negotiate
> blahblahblahblah
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Cookie:CFID=11801; CFTOKEN=90037336; LASTVISIT=1327716554490
>
> Host:localhost
>
> Referer:http://localhost/sitename/index.cfm?file=filename/filename.cfm&Config=filename
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7
>
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
>
> Query String Parameters view URL encoded
>
> file:error.cfm
>
> Response Headers view source
>
> Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date:Fri, 27 Jan 2012 21:09:14
>
> GMT Persistent-Auth:true Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>
> Set-Cookie:LASTVISIT=1327716554533;expires=Wed, 25-Jul-2012 21:09:14 GMT;path=/
>
> Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>
> X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Comment: Not noted, but please clarify what version and what kind of CF? Abode, Railo, Blue Dragon, etc so other people may have more insight. Second, has tying location url="/index.cfm?file=error.cfm" worked?

Comment: Do this please: in Google Chrome, go to the menu (wrench), select Tools -> Developer Tools; a pane will open up below your page. Click the 3rd tab (Network), and then...re-run the test where you throw the error within the CFC. Take a screenshot of the network activity and add it to your question.

Comment: Having a redirect onError is a bad idea - you are setting yourself up for an infinite loop. If anything goes wrong in your application.cfc/application.cfm or the file you are redirecting to, the cycle will start repeating infinitely. You should instead include an error template to avoid this fate. You'll want all of the HTML that should be generated when an error occurs in this file.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing the 302 Redirect, which is absent from your updated question, and also absent from the discussion in the answer below. I set up a test locally, threw an error within the CFC, and had the cflocation fire correctly, and noted the 302 in in the network traffic, yet yours doesn't show, which means something else is interrupting it.

Comment: Shawn, I've added output that shows the 302 redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got my answer here:

[Handling Remote API Errors With Application.cfc's OnError Event Method](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1567-Handling-Remote-API-Errors-With-Application-cfc-s-OnError-Event-Method.htm)

Guess I know just enough Ajax to be dangerous :(

I think what threw me is that I could see that cflocation was indeed redirecting to the error pages and that I could see the correct response in the network pane; but what I didn't realize is that since I was calling the function remotely, the browser will never actually go to the new window, and instead, the response is sitting there waiting to be handled by the ajax call itself. I'll figure this stuff out eventually.

Comment: This is the solution to your problem. Just remember that AJAX is client side. Although you are calling a server function you will never see what happens server side unless you pass it back to the client. What do I mean by this? If you output anything or perform a redirect on the server side you will never see what happens server side unless you pass it back to the client in the results. (don't forget to mark your question answered.)

Comment: Yes, thanks, Stephen... must keep repeating to myself: client side, client side, client side....

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, misread the question...

UPDATED:  You could try including a template to handle the cflocation, doing a cflocation inside the application.cfc might be disallowed since its happening before the request is fired?

Application.cfc

```
 component {

    this.name = 'errorTest';

    public void function onError(required any Exception, required string EventName) {

        include 'errorRedirect.cfm';
    }
}
```

index.cfm (has an error in the code for demo)

```
<cfscript>
a = form.nonExistentVariable;
</cfscript>
```

errorRedirect.cfm

```
<cflocation url="error.html">
```

error.html

```
<h1>Sorry, An Error has Occurred. </h1>
```

test.cfc (test with test.cfc?method=test to demo cfc based error)

```
component {

remote function test () {

    a = form.DoesNotExist;
}
}
```

Comment: Ben, do you mean doing the include inside the onError() method? I'd already tried that, to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, I just provided a full working example which worked for me on CF9, I don't have access to a lower version CF server to test on others right now.

Comment: Ben, we're using Application.cfc, not .cfm.

Comment: Can you provide a demo of the CFC and the kind of error being thrown by it?  PS> Yes, application.cfc is fine.  Tested as well.  Worked as expected.

Comment: Ben, not getting an error - Chrome reports that the page was loaded and the response in the Network pane shows the correct html... but the browser doesn't actually show that updated html.

Comment: oh, I see you're including a redirect.cfm which actually calls the cflocation. will try that.

Comment: Installed Chrome: Tested and same results.  Is it just Chrome that's doing that for you?

Comment: Just a side note too: If you include a cfm file directly within the OnError method, it won't call OnError again if there's an error in that error handling file -- avoiding an infinite error loop.  However, if you cflocation to a cfm page with an error, you can get a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the below link might help you

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2050-Changes-In-CFLocation-OnRequestEnd-Behavior-In-ColdFusion-9-s-Application-cfc.htm

Comment: that's interesting, but I don't think it's relevant here, as I don't have OnRequestEnd() defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AJAX then the resulting output will not display unless bound to an HTML element in the HTML document using CF.

Can you see any content in the response body (the entity) for error page using chrome when you make the AJAX request?

I take it this is a Bluedragon application server?